# Obtener keys y values duplicados de un objeto con desctructuring

Tags: javascript, array, javascript-objeto

Estoy intentado recorrer un objeto y almacenar los values de cada key en otro. El problema es que los keys de este objeto están duplicados y no me está funcionando el código que tengo.

**Me explico mejor con el codigo**

El objeto con toda la informacion es este:

```
mapp = {
"https://compliance.com/": "Empresa", 
"https://compliance.com/": "Contacto",
"https://compliance.com/": "Last",
"https://compliance.com/blog/": "Blog Compliance",
"https://compliance.com/blog/": "Noticias Compliance"}
```

Lo que pretendo es construir otro objeto con todos los keys sin duplicar, y que almacene todos los values concatenados.

Para ello tengo un array con todas las keys (urls), sin duplicar:

```
urls = ["https://compliance.com/", "https://compliance.com/blog/"]
```

Y preparo un objeto que sería el que pretendo construir:

```
ancObj = {
    "https://compliance.com/" : [], 
    "https://compliance.com/blog/" : []
  }
```

Y este sería el código que tengo para el objetivo descrito:

```
const iterator = urls.map(url => {
    let exp = '^'+url+'$'
    let regex = new RegExp(exp)
    for(const [key,value] of Object.entries(mapp)){
    if(regex.test(key)){
    ancObj[url].push(value)
      }}
    }
```

Lo que hago es recorrer el array con las URLs no duplicadas y luego iterar el objeto donde esta toda la informacion. Por destructuring compruebo si la URL se encuentra en dicho objeto, y si se cumple, hago push del value en el objeto que quiero construir. El problema es que no me pushea todos los values, sino el último valor.

El output es este:

```
  ancObj =  { 'https://compliance.com/': [ 'Last' ],
      'https://compliance.com/blog/': [ 'Noticias Compliance' ] }
```

Y me gustaría que fuese:

```
{ 'https://compliance.com/': [ 'Empresa, Contacto, Last' ],
  'https://compliance.com/blog/': [ 'Blog Compliance, Noticias Compliance' ] }
```

Comment: Pregunta, ¿como es que llegas a tener ese objeto mal construido?, no es posible recorrer (de forma natural) un objeto que tiene claves con igual valor, ¿tenes posibilidad de modificar la creacion de ese objeto?

Comment: "El output es este:" porque las claves iguales se ignoran, solo se toma la ultima.

Comment: No es posible modificar ese objeto, es la información que tengo como input y que tengo que transformar

Comment: De donde estas recibiendo eso? como estas seguro que llega de esa forma?, JS no contempla ese tipo de objetos y no mucho que puedas hacer para gestionarlo.